# update table from other error in mysql XAMPP

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update table from other but I got error this is my query

```
UPDATE items
SET items.Price = prix.Price from items,prix WHERE items.ID = prix.ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `update ... from` Syntax. You have to use `update ... join`:

```
UPDATE items join prix on items.ID = prix.ID
SET items.Price = prix.Price
```

Comment: Thank u so Much That what I want exactely